# Re-engineer POJOs to EJBs or client transaction

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, transactions, timeout, ejb-3.1

I have a couple of questions regarding EJB transactions. I have a situation where a process has become longer running that originally intended and is sometimes failing due to server timeout's being exceeded. While I have increased the timeouts initially (both total transaction and max transaction), for a long running process, I know that it make more sense to segment this work as much as possible into smaller units of work that don't fail based on timeout. As a result, I'm looking for some thoughts or references regarding next course of action based on the background below and the questions that follow.

**Environment:**
EJB 3.1, JPA 2.0, WebSphere 8.5

**Background:**
I built a set of POJOs to do some batch oriented work for an enterprise application. They are non-EJB POJOs that were intended to implement several business processes (5 related, sequential processes, each depending on it's predecessor). The POJOs are in a plain Java project, not an EJB project.

However, these POJOs access an EJB facade for database access via JPA. The abstract core of the 5 business processes does the JNDI lookup for the EJB facade in order to return the domain objects for processing. Originally, the design was to run from the server completely, however, a need arose to initiate these processes externally. As a result, I created an EJB wrapper so that the processes could be called remotely (individually or as a single process based on a common strategy interface). Unfortunately, the size of the data, both row width and row count, has grown well beyond the original intent.

The processing time required to complete these batch processes has increased significantly (from around a couple of hours to around 1/2 a day and could increase beyond that). Only one of the 5 processes made sense to multi-thread (I did implement it multi-threaded). Since I have the wrapper EJB to initiate 1 or all, I have decided to create a new container transaction for each process as opposed to the single default transaction of "required" when I run all as a single process. Since the one process is multi-threaded, it would make sense to attempt to create a new transaction per thread, however, being a group of POJOs, I do not have transaction capability.

**Question:**
So my question is, what makes more sense and why? Re-engineer the POJOs to be EJBs themselves and have the wrapper EJB instantiate each process as a child process where each can have its own transaction and more importantly, the multi-threaded process can create a transaction per thread. Or does it make more sense to attempt to create a UserTransaction in the POJOs from a JNDI lookup in the container and try to manage it as if it were a bean managed transaction (if that's even a viable solution). I know this may be application dependent, but what is reasonable with regard to timeouts for a Java EE container? Obviously, I don't want run away processes, but want to make sure that I can complete these batch processes.

Unfortunatly, this application has already been deployed as a production system. Re-engineering, though it may be little more than assembling the strategy logic in EJBs, is a large change to the functionality.

I did look around for some other threads here and via general internet searches, but thought I would see if anyone had compelling arguments for one over the other or another solution entirely. Additional links that talk about a topic such as this are appreciated. I wrestled with whether to post this since some may construe this as subjective, however, I felt the narrowed topic was worth the post and potentially relevant to others attempting processes like this.

Comment: Arjan, thank you for correcting my uppercase and punctuation. I'll try to remember that the case and punctuation is important for these posts. Just my bad habits I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I really didn't get a whole lot of response or thoughts for this question over the past couple of weeks, I figured I would answer this question to hopefully help others in making a decision if they run across this or a similar situation.

Ultimately, I re-engineered one of the POJOs into an EJB that acted as a wrapper to call the other POJOs. The wrapper EJB performed the same activity as when it was just a POJO, except for the fact that I added the transaction semantics (REQUIRES_NEW) on the primary method. The primary method calls the other POJOs based on a stategy pattern so each call (or POJO) gets its own transaction. Other methods in the EJB that call the primary method were defined with NOT_SUPPORTED so that I could separate the transactions for each call to the primary method and not join an existing transaction.

Full disclosure, the original addition of transaction semantics significantly increased the processing time (on the order of days), but the process did not fail due to exceeding transaction timeouts. It was the result of some unexpected problems with JPA Many-To-One relationships that were bringing back too much data. Data retreived as a result of a the Many-To-One relationship. As I mentioned originally, some of my data row width increased unexpectedly. That data increase was in the related table object, but the query did not need that data at the time. I corrected those issues by changing my queries (creating objects for SELECT NEW queries, changed relationships to FetchType.LAZY, etc).

Going forward, if I am able to dedicate enough time, I will transform the rest of those POJOs into EJBs. The POJO doing the most significant amount of work that is threaded has been implemented with a Callable implementation that is run via an ExecutorService. If I can transform that one, the plan will be to make each thread its own transaction. However, while I'm not sure yet, it appears that my container may already be creating transactions for each thread group (of 10 threads) due to status updates I'm seeing. I will have to do more investigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to your question, but something you could consider. 
WebSphere 8.5 especially for these kind of applications  (batch) provides a batch container. The batch function accommodate applications that must perform batch work alongside transactional applications. Batch work might take hours or even days to finish and uses large amounts of memory or processing power while it runs. You can reuse your Java classes in batch applications, batch steps can be run in parallel in cluster and has transaction checkpoint management.

Take a look at following resources:

[IBM Education Assistant - Batch applications](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v8/was/WASv85.html)
[Getting started with the batch environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cgrid_xdbgcmp.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thank you. I am aware the batch container exists in WAS, but don't know a lot about it and have not used so far. I have wrestled with using it because I didn't think it was portable, but maybe it doesn't have to be. Thank you for the reference, I have looked at them briefly.  I'm sure that for a long running process, it will help, but will require some rearchitecting that I'm not sure I can tackle right now (making a new EAR, etc.). Can I take some existing JARs as they exist from my application, create a batch EAR application, and run? Or would I have to separate functionality?